# How to check if checkboxes are selected and add integers accordingly

Tags: java, swing, applet

```
private void costShippingButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                        
    calculateCost();
}                                                  

public static double calculateCost () {
    double computerPrice = 500;
    double headsetPrice = 80;
    double keyboardPrice = 100;
    double mousePrice = 50;
    double mousepadPrice = 10;
    double usbPrice = 20;
    double monitorPrice = 150;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm new to coding and I'm doing this assignment, an applet, that will calculate the cost of certain computer peripherals but I need to know how to be able to check if certain check-boxes are selected and will add an integer according to what is selected. So for example I select the monitor and mouse check-boxes, I need the program to add those two together automatically and so on. (Ignore the return, just a placeholder)

Comment: See Java Tutorial on Check Boxes [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes it's just what the teacher asking for it.

Comment: *"Yes it's just what the teacher asking for it."* So just give the teacher that link, as my message to them. :)  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).